# Equation of the line that has $x$ and $y$ intercepts at $a$ and $b$.

Tags: analytic-geometry

Please can anyone help me with proving the following problem:

> Show that the line that crosses the $X$-axis at $a \neq 0$ and the $Y$-axis at $b \neq 0$ has the equation $$\dfrac{x}a + \dfrac{y}b -1=0$$

I don't have an idea of where I should start from for proving the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $x$ intercept is given by $(a, 0)$, and the $y$ intercept is given by $(0, b)$. And we know $a \neq 0, b\neq 0$, so the points are distinct.

All you need to do is substitute these values into your equation to see that equality holds: i.e., that they lie on the line defined by $$\frac xa + \frac yb - 1 = 0$$

$$(a, 0): x = a, y = 0 \implies  \frac aa + \frac 0b - 1 = 0\implies \frac aa = 1\implies 1 = 1\quad \checkmark$$

$$(0, b): x = 0, y = b \implies \frac 0a + \frac bb - 1 = 0 \implies \frac bb = 1 \implies 1 = 1 \quad \checkmark$$

Indeed: These are unique points lying on the line given by $$\frac xa + \frac yb - 1 = 0$$

Comment: Let me know, Samama, if you have any questions about this! :-)

Comment: Yeah, sure. Thanks :)

Comment: I've no questions indeed. The explanation is quite comprehensible, and I just needed an idea. But you guys have really proved the whole problem. However, thanks for that.

Comment: @amWhy: very nice write up +1

Comment: in question where is it state that the line will only cut X and Y axis on their positive side?so why every one thinking only 1 case that interception points are only (a,0) and (0,b).I don't agree with this.

Answer (score 2):

- Clearly, the equation $\dfrac{x}a + \dfrac{y}b - 1 =0 $ defines a straight line.
- Also, two distinct points uniquely define a straight line.
- Now check that $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ satisfy the equation.
- This would imply $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ lie on the straight line.
- Since $a \neq 0 \neq b$, these are two distinct distinct points.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you have two points from the problem description: $(a, 0)$, and $(0, b)$. Can you write the equation of a line connecting them?

If you are still stuck:

Using slope-intercept form, we have:

$$y = \frac{y_{2} - y_{1}}{x_{2} - x_{1}}x + b$$ where $b$ is the $y$-intercept and $(x_{1}, y_{1}), (x_{2}, y_{2})$ are two points on the line. Evaluating, then, we see:

$$y = \frac{b - 0}{0-a}x + b = \frac{-b}{a}x + b$$
$$\implies y + \frac{b}{a}x - b = 0$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{b}y + \frac{1}{a}x - 1 = 0$$ 
$$\implies \frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} - 1 = 0$$

Comment: how did you get $\frac {1}{b}y + \frac {1}{a}x - 1 = 0$?

Comment: I divided both sides by $b$ (or if you'd like, multiplied both sides by $\frac{1}{b})$, which is fine as $b \neq 0$. Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Thanks. That is also a good answer and a comprehensible answer. No questions indeed.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there are set of 4 lines. because intercepts are length and its coordinates have set of 4 coordinates.(a,0)(0,b),(a,0)(0,-b),(-a,0)(0,b),(-a,0)(0,-b).
so lines equation will be..
$$ \frac xa + \frac yb -1 =0$$

$$ \frac xa - \frac yb -1 =0$$

$$ -\frac xa + \frac yb -1 =0$$
$$ -\frac xa - \frac yb -1 =0$$

Comment: The equation of the line **is given.** It is the **one** equation you list **first.** And the points given where the lines crosses the x-axis is when $x = a$ and the y-axis is when $y = b$. That means it intersects the x-axis at $(a, 0)$, and it intersects the y-axis at $(0, b)$. So I'm afraid your answer may just confuse the OP, not help.

Comment: @amWhy please read carefully the question it is saying "that Show that the line that crosses the X-axis at a≠0 and the Y-axis at b≠0 has given equation" means OP has to prove that line equation.I'm just saying that here only stated that a≠0,b≠0 doesn't say that these point are on positive axis so they can be on any axis.from just interceptor length we can't decide which point has to taken.

Comment: peoples are too fast to downvote without consider any option

Comment: @SamamaFahim it is exactly same in your problem.Their is not  mention that a and b must be positive their is only mention that a and b are not equal to 0.